# django, mod_wsig , KeyError Threading ignored

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

I am getting this error from mod_wsgi:

```
[Thu Feb 24 23:31:33 2011] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140115471374144,) in <module 'threading'from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

I am using virtualenv with mod_wsgi, I have set python-path like this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ubuntu python-path=/home/ubuntu/to/my/site-packages
```

Any ideas ,plz

Answer (score 1):

The message is [harmless](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=197). Fix added in late release.